# Swap first 2 rows of a 2d Python list without Numpy?

Tags: python, list

How can I swap the first 2 rows of a 2D Python list **without** using Numpy?
For example, if my list is:

```
lst = [[0,3,2],
       [4,3,2],
       [3,5,2]]
```

I want to swap `[0,3,2]` with `[4,3,2]`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Or do you need it to be a function to swap when needed?

```
lst = [[0,3,2],
       [4,3,2],
       [3,5,2]]

lst[0], lst[1] = lst[1], lst[0]
print(lst)
# [[4, 3, 2], 
# [0, 3, 2], 
# [3, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

store the second value (lst[1]) in a temporary variable swap the variable

```
lst = [[0,3,2],
       [4,3,2],
       [3,5,2]]
a= lst[1]
lst[1] = lst[0]
lst[0] = a
```

hope it helps :)